I'm encountering "SMPTHeloError: (501, b'Syntactically invalid HELO argument(s)')" on one device but not others
I'm making a program that is supposed to regularly send me emails so that I can do regular status checks on work equipment. The computer I need to use the program on gives me the error SMPTHeloError: (501, b'Syntactically invalid HELO argument(s)'), why does this show up and how do I get rid of this error?
When I test on my personal laptop, the code executes just fine, and when I test on another computer it works just fine. I've looked around for solutions, but all I could find was the host name being potentially wrong, but I checked my devices' name and it does not have any underscores or invalid characters and is structured the same way as my personal laptop, which has no issues executing the code.
Here's an example python code to reproduce the issue:
import smtplib, ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg=EmailMessage()
msg['From'] = "Status Updater <example@example.com>"
msg['To'] = "John Doe <example@example.com>"
msg.set_content("Email Contents")
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("mail.example.com", 465, context=context) as server:
    server.login('example@example.com', "password")
    server.send_message(msg)


This error comes not from your computer but the mail server you are talking to. And to understand the error we would need to know the actual name you are using as argument instead of "mail.domain.com" (also - use example.com for examples instead of arbitrary domains owned by a real entitity)

Can you please [edit] to show the transcript with SMTP.set_debuglevel(1) so we can see what the problematic HELO is?

The host name DESKTOP-7HJ08AV.NetisRouter_64eeb7fe9daa is what it's complaining about; I guess your other hosts have something less unsightly. The underscore in particular is invalid I believe.

@tripleee how would I go about changing it? I'm not sure where it's getting the .NetisRouter part, would that be my internet router?

I'm guessing this is a WIndows computer and it gets its name from some sort of domain controller, or maybe your wifi router? IIRC you can override the HELO explicitly but then you will need to figure out how to provide something useful there. Perhaps a better solution is to make the responsible service give the box a less ghastly name. What does the HELO string look like on the other computer where this code is working?

The question should remain strictly a question; posting an answer like you already did is exactly how to solve it. It's not clear that this is actually really programming-related, though.

By using the debug transcript I figured out that what was causing the error was indeed an underscore in the hostname, but it wasn't because of the device name. It seems it appends the Connection Specific DNS Suffix at the end of your hostname (and that Suffix had an underscore in it) and I needed to edit that in order to stop the error from happening anymore. This is the guide I used in order to change the DNS Suffix.
